# Change colours on Msys

Tags: ssh, msys

I like to use Msys for SSH (because Putty complicates matters with its non-standard ssh keys), but when I request a directory listing (`ls`) in an SSH session, subdirectories are listed in a blue colour which is altogether unreadable against the black background.

Can anyone tell me of a way to configure Msys to give me different a colour for directories? I don't actually wish to disable colours globally, but I would like directories to be given a different colour.

Comment: For the record: SSH keys used by OpenSSH aren't standard either. AFAIK, only SSH.com *public* key format was ever standartized as a RFC... anyway, PuTTYgen can import/export the OpenSSH format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change blue color in console palette (to make it brighter), right click console window title and follow the popup menu.